# Having trouble reading directly from VEML6075 UV sensor from its registers(I2C)

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I'm kinda new to Arduino and decided to dive deeper into learning abit more about Arduino; So i decided to grab a Sparkfun VEML6075 UV sensor and try to:

1) Initialise it
2) Take readings from it

Without using the Sparkfun libraries at all. Based on what I read in the datasheets, this seems possible by using the I2C communication protocol provided by communicating directly with the registers of the device itself.

However, I can't seem to be able to even initialise the device properly as the readings I have gotten are weird and do not change (I presume this means the device only took one reading and stops at that)

My code is as below:

```
#include <Wire.h>

byte address = 0x10; // Slave address of the VEML6075
byte UVA_LSB, UVA_MSB;
word UVA_data;
uint16_t UVA_combined;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Wire.begin();
    VEML6075_init(address);
//    uv.begin();
    Serial.println("Module is detected");
}

void loop() {
    VEML6075_Fetch_UV(address);   // Fetch UVA data *TEST*
    Serial.print("UVA: ");
    Serial.println(UVA_combined);
    delay(1000);
}

// shutdown module and init it; restarting the module 
void VEML6075_init(byte address){
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);  // Shutdown command 
    Wire.write(highByte(0x00));
    Wire.write(lowByte(0x01));
    Wire.endTransmission();

    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    Wire.write(highByte(0x00));
    Wire.write(lowByte(0x12));   // Reset command using conf register
    Wire.endTransmission();
    delay(200); // Wait for module to reset 
    // Done //
  }

 void VEML6075_Fetch_UV(byte address){
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);   // Begin transmission into I2C line with Slave address 
    Wire.write(highByte(0x07));     // Issue command to read UVA data 
    Wire.write(lowByte(0x07));
    Wire.requestFrom(address, 2);
    while(!Wire.available()); // Needs refining; read twice for 16 bits
    UVA_LSB = Wire.read();
    UVA_MSB = Wire.read();  
    Wire.endTransmission();

    UVA_combined = ((UVA_MSB << 8) | UVA_LSB); // Combine to 16bits
  }
```

As stated in the datasheet:

> The VEML6075 contains a CONF register (00h) used for operation control and parameter setup. Measurement results are stored
>   in four separate registers, one each for UVA, UVB, UVcomp1, and UVcomp2 (07h to 0Bh respectively). All registers are accessible
>   via I2C communication. Fig. 7 shows the basic I2C communication with the VEML6075. Each of the registers in the
>   VEML6075 are 16 bit wide, so 16 bit should be written when a write command is sent, and 16 bit should be read when a read
>   command is sent.

I have allocated 16 bits for receiving the data, and have also used the conf address 0x12 to set the timing to 100ms and activate active-force-mode which i presume is the device taking readings automatically. The readings given are way off the accurate readings given when i upload a example code that uses the Sparkfun library, so I'm quite lost at this point. How am I using the I2C protocol wrongly? Thanks!

Comment: add `Wire.endTransmission(false);` to send the written bytes before `Wire.requestFrom(address, 2);`

Comment: after `Wire.requestFrom(address, 2);` returns, the data are available for read

Comment: ... thus the line with `while(!Wire.available())` can be removed. The highbyte and lowbyte are used in the wrong way. When a 16-bit variable is for example 0x1234, then the highbyte is 12 and the lowbyte is 34. You use already bytes.

Comment: Could you explain further about what you mean by I'm using highbytes wrongly and in where? In my intitalisation function I used Wire.write(highByte(0x00));
    Wire.write(lowByte(0x12));  to emulate 0x0012 for 16bits conf register. Is that correct?

Comment: 0x00 is already a byte and 0x12 is already a byte. You can do `highByte(0x0012)` and `lowByte(0x0012)`. If you already pick the bytes from 0x0012 then you can do `Wire.write(0x00); // high byte` and `Wire.write(0x12); // low byte`

Comment: Do you use a i2c level shifter?